# Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Tags: excel, vba, function, runtime

Hoping you can help me to debug this error. Macro was previously working perfectly, I've made no changes and now facing the variable error - Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set.

On dubug it's highlighting the line:  ValueFound = FindValue(RangeHeader.Text,TableCollection). Where FindValue is another function.

Fucntion A:

```
Function Alpha(aTableCollection As Collection)

    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim RangeHeader As Range
    Dim RangeValue As Range
    Dim TableCollection As Collection
    Dim SupplierName As String
    Dim Counter
    Dim endColumn As Integer

    Set TableCollection = New Collection
    Set TableCollection = aTableCollection

    SupplierName = aTableCollection.Item(4)

    With Sheets("Suppliers").Range("B:B")
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=SupplierName, After:=.Cells(.Cells.count), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:= _
                    xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
        Set Sheet = ActiveSheet
        Set RangeHeader = Range("A1")
    End With

    ValueFound = Beta(RangeHeader.Text, TableCollection)

    RangeValue.Offset(0, 1).FormulaR1C1 = ValueFound

    endColumn = Sheet.UsedRange.Columns.count

    Counter = 1 
    While Counter < endColumn 
        ValueFound = Beta(RangeHeader.Offset(0, Counter).Text, TableCollection)
        RangeValue.Offset(0, Counter).FormulaR1C1 = ValueFound
    Counter = Counter + 1 
    Wend

End Function
```

Function Beta:

```
Function Beta(aNameToFind As Variant, aCollection As Collection) As Variant

Dim MyObject As Variant
Dim count As Integer

For Each MyObject In aCollection    
    count = count + 1
    If aNameToFind = MyObject Then   
        count = count + 1
        Beta = aCollection.Item(count)  
        Exit For
    End If 
Next

End Function
```

If anyone has any ideas how to fix this error (and maybe knows why it's only recently started to show this error)  it would be much appreciated.

Any clarifications needed, just ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I do not see the `ValueFound = FindValue(RangeHeader.Text,TableCollection)` in your code.

Comment: Pretty sure he means:  `ValueFound = Beta(RangeHeader.Text, TableCollection)`

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is in Beta().

It includes this line twice:

```
count = count + 1
```

I suspect that is causing the wrong item to be returned from the collection.

Try removing the 2nd occurrence of the above line.

Actually, the Beta() routine appears completely pointless. Why not just skip it altogether with this line:

```
ValueFound = TableCollection(RangeHeader.Text)
```